# "starting home folder" issue in gnome classic nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, gnome-classic

When I open Nautilus in ubuntu 12.04 gnome-session-fallback, it shows two tabs in the panel, one is my Nautilus, the other "starting home folder" (encircled green) stays there for 10-15 seconds and then disappears. I don't want it to appear. Anyone have any idea why this happens and can I have a solution for it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue. I found there were two applications called "Files" in `/usr/share/applications/` plus one called "Home Folder". The command for these was `nautilus %u` so I was pretty sure they had something to do with the problem. Anyway, removing these on their own didn't work, so this is what I did:

1. Open terminal and type `alacarte` (this opens the menu for editing). Remove "Files" from the "Accessories" menu (it may be there twice, remove both). Close menu.
2. Type `sudo nautilus` in terminal, navigate to `/usr/share/applications/` and remove both "Files" and "Home Folder" applications.
3. Log off and on again.
4. Edit the menu as in step 1 and re-create the "Files" item with the command `nautilus %u`.
5. Type `nautilus` in a terminal, pick any folder and right click on it, select "open with other application", then "browse", then choose the "Files" item you just created.

After step 3 you will not be able to open any folders unless you run the command `nautilus` in a terminal, steps 4 and 5 fix this.

This worked for me but I have no idea if it is the best/quickest/safest or stupidest way.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the icon by editing the menu and clicking on the properties of the "File" entry. This will open a properties box with the icon in the top right corner, click on it and you can navigate to a new icon. I used /usr/share/icons/Humanity/places/32/folder.svg

Good tip about right clicking the icon to edit the menu, at last something is actually easier in gnome-classic!

Drew

Comment: I have the same issue and can confirm Drew's solution worked for me, just one comment and one additional question (if I may): Comment: step 1.: if you use gnome-classic, you can just right-click the menu bar and 'edit menu' Question (just a minor issue): the File icon has dissappeared in the menu and changed into a Tintin launcher rocket; how can I get the original icon back? There is also no entry 'file' in /usr/share/applications (?) Thanx for the solution, Drew.

Answer (score 0):

This issue affects to gnome session (no classic) too, but there we don't see "starting home folder" there, we only see the busy mouse for thats 10-15 seconds.
I discovered it's a login session issue, I don't know why, but when I have autologin it happens, and when I log manualy nautilus work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Only use nautilus command without %U . It works for me.